# Blocking of docker-compose up on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, docker, containers, docker-compose

I am trying to automate the lauching of my containers with docker-compose. 
"Docker build" and "docker-compose build" are successfully completed but I have a problem when I launch "docker-compose up".

Indeed, the process works fine until it arrives to this line (in the mysql container) :

```
mysql_1    | Version: '5.7.17'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'   port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

None errors appears, but the process is waiting for hours and I have to stop it manually.

This problem appeared when I upgraded my os to Ubuntu 16.04 (the docker files worked in the 14.04 version).

Hope you will find a solution.

Thank you.

Comment: By "wait" do you mean that the mysql server is not working / responding? Or just that you never get your prompt back? `docker-compose up` without the `-d` flag will stay attached and you will not get your prompt back. Use `-d` to run in the background instead.

Comment: (The line you show is the normal last line of output when the server starts up successfully.)

Comment: Thanks for your comment Dan. 
By "wait" I mean that I have never my prompt back. I have tried with the -d and there is no problem. 
But when i go to the ip address to display my website I have just this message : 

" An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)"

I thought the origin of my problem was the mysql container but I will search an other way to resolve that.

Comment: If your mysql is in a separate container than your web app, you can't use 127.0.0.1 to connect to it. Each container has its own separate localhost (127.0.0.1).

Comment: Thank you Dan, you found the solution ! The problem was that I haven't change my parameters.yml (my website is made on symfony 3) and the ip address was wrong. Thank you !